# What does $ \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^l $ mean?

Tags: calculus

I know what $ \mathbb{R}^n $ means, set of n tuples of real numbers, but I dont understand what this as a whole means nor how to imagine it
$  \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^l $ and
$\Omega  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ is continuous.

Comment: It is not a cross product but a cartesian product.

Comment: And it is technically not equality. Sometimes $\cong$ is preferred to make clear they aren't the same thing, just isomorphic. In this particularly case, the isomorphism is so trivial, we often think of them as 'the same.' Of course, they are only isomorphic if $k+l=n.$

Answer (score 4):

Since we define the Cartesian product by
$$
S \times T := \{ (s,t) \mid s \in S, t \in T \}
$$
it naturally follows that
$$
\mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^\ell = \{ (x,y) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}^k, y \in \mathbb{R}^\ell \}
$$
or equivalently
$$
\mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^\ell = \left\{ \Big( (x_1,\cdots,x_k),(y_1,\cdots,y_\ell) \Big) \, \Big| \, x_i,y_i \in \mathbb{R} \text{ for every } i \right\}
$$
It is not hard to show that this space is (in basically any sense you want) isomorphic to the space
$$
\mathbb{R}^{k+\ell} := \{ (z_1,\cdots,z_{k+\ell}) \mid z_1,\cdots,z_{k+\ell} \in \mathbb{R}\}
$$
Hence $\mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^\ell = \mathbb{R}^n$ really means that (up to isomorphism, since the elements are technically not identical) that $n = k+\ell$, i.e. that $\mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^\ell \cong \mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R}^{k+\ell}$.

---

The subset relation is what you expect. If $A \subseteq B$, then each element of $A$ lives in $B$, i.e. $x \in A \implies x \in B$. Depending on the author's preference, $\subset$ may allow equality, or may not.

---

If a function $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous, it just means that the function (call it $f$) has inputs which lie in $\Omega$, and whenever $G \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set, then the preimage
$$
f^{-1}(G) := \{ x \in \Omega \mid f(x) \in G \}
$$
is an open set. There are several other equivalent definitions, some using the metric space structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I didn't understand about the isomorphism. How can it be isomorph, if both Space have different set of tuples?

Comment: The elements don't have to be the exact same, they just have to behave the exact same. To show that $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\R^k \times \R^\ell \cong \R^{k+\ell}$, define
$$\begin{align*}
\varphi : \R^k \times \R^\ell &\to \R^{k+\ell} \\
\Big( (x_1,\cdots,x_k) \; ,\;  (y_1,\cdots,y_\ell) \Big) &\mapsto (x_1,\cdots,x_k,y_1,\cdots,y_\ell)
\end{align*}$$
and show the necessary properties of an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

The symbol $\times$ gets overloaded a bit in different areas. Here, it means the Cartesian product of two sets.

Given two sets $A$ and $B$, the Cartesian product $A \times B$ is the collection of all ordered pairs of the form $(a, b)$. That is,

$$ A \times B = \{ (a, b) \ : a \in A, \ b \in B \}$$

So what about here? Well,

$$ \mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^l = \{ ((x_1, \ldots, x_k), (y_1, \ldots, y_l)) \ : x \in \mathbb{R}^k, \ y \in \mathbb{R}^l \} $$

so that set is just an ordered pair of two vectors. Note, however, that this is not the same as $\mathbb{R}^{k+l}$ but you can define an isomorphism between the two spaces!